# MovieClip doesn't dispatch mouse event after nesting MovieClip loaded from external SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, movieclip

Mostly, problem is described in the title... I tried to load an external SWF file that contains some named MovieClip instances (exporting and naming is done by Flash CS5 software) and to add some of externaly loaded (named) MovieClip-s in MovieClip object which is created in my code. Problem appears when i add MOUSE_CLICK listener to parent MovieClip. Simply, it does not dispatch event when i click on it at the stage...

```
private var loader:Loader;

public function Example(){
    loader = new Loader();
    var request:URLRequest = ... // URL to external SWF
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadingCompleted)
    loader.load(request);
}

private function loadingCompleted(event:Event):void{
    var mc:MovieClip = loader.content as MovieClip;
    var myMovie:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); 
    myMovie.addChild(mc.getChildByName("object_name"));
    myMovie.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myMovieClicked);
    addChild(myMovie); // myMovie (with nested mc) appears on the stage
}

private function myMovieClicked(evt:Event):void{
//never reached
}
```

**EDIT:** I didn't mention that i'm working in Flex using FlashBuilder 4.5 where i created ActionScript project. Code above is body of Example class, which is main SWF class.

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER:** `myMovie.mouseChildren = false` solves the problem. Earlier i tried to set `mouseEnabled = true`, and it didn't fix the problem. But i'm confused about event flow now... Even if child is target node, why mouse listener on parent MovieClip doesn't recieve event (in capture phase) when parent is still on event flow? Moreover, when i create another movie clip in my code (whit some simple shape inside) and add it to myMovie, everything works fine. What is so special when i obtain movie clip from externaly loaded SWF?

Comment: Can you provide nested .fla? I've done it a lot of times, but I haven't had problems like this.

Comment: .fla is very simple. It contains one movie clip symbol (which contains simple rectangle shape) with defined instance name. When i add click listener to named MovieClip instance itself (instance obtained with getChildByName in the code above), and then nest it in myMovie, everything works fine... Problem appears when i add listener to myMovie - MovieClip instance that is parent to named instance.

Comment: Can you try this sample? https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7pqls_VbwLaU0ZOSld1UTZhSjA

Comment: Sample works :) But i didn't mention that I work in flex, sorry for that. I use FlashBuilder 4.5, where i created ActionScript project. Code, that i wrote in question, is body of Example (main SWF) class. But still, code in the sample is same as mine, and it works when i publish SWF-s from Flash, and doesn't work when i compile it in FlashBuilder. I just don't get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing `myMovie.mouseEnabled = true` and `myMovie.mouseChildren = false` ?

Comment: It works!!! Thank you very much Antonie. Earlier i tried to set mouseEnabled = true, and it didn't fix the problem. myMovie.mouseChildren = false solves the problem. But i'm confused about event flow now... Even if child is target node, why mouse listener on parent MovieClip doesn't recieve event (in capture phase) when parent is still on event flow. More over, when i create another movie clip in my code (whit some simple shape inside) and add it to myMovie, everything works fine. What is so special when i obtain movie clip from externaly loaded SWF?

Comment: It may come from security restrictions must not quite sure about it.